# Close all divs except the one that is opened with childs

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list (tree) with some nested unordered lists, and so on... What I want to accomplish is to hide all `.subnav`'s that are not inside the clicked `li > a`.

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/429C8/2/).

Example:

Click `A` => `A1` and `A2` is opened

Click `A1` => `A1-a` and `A1-b` is opened

Click `A2` => `A2-a` and `A2-b` is opened, **and `A1` should be closed**

Click `B` => `B1` and `B2` is opened, **and whole `A` should be closed**

I want to hide everything in the main `ul` which is not needed, leaving only the element that is clicked. It should work with unlimited nesting :)

I tried different things, but none worked as expected:

```
$('.subnav').not(subnav).hide();
$('.subnav').not(that).hide();
$('.subnav').not(this).hide();
```

I have no idea how to accomplish this behaviour.

Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its simplest, I'd suggest:

```
$('.nav > li > a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('.subnav').toggle()
    // find the ancestor 'li' elements:
    .parents('li')
    // select the siblings (also 'li' elements):
    .siblings()
    // find the '.subnav' elements within those sibling 'li' elements:
    .find('.subnav')
    // hide them:
    .hide();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/429C8/3/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: OMG this works! I would never guess that, it's so complicated, and took you 1 min to answer :D Thanks David!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! :)